# Move Robot in a 10 X 10 grid

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I am working on this code challenge:

> Given a 2D bot/robot which can only move in four directions, move forward which is UP(U), move backward which is DOWN(D), LEFT(L), RIGHT(R) in a 10x10 grid. The robot can't go beyond the 10x10 area.
>
> Given a string consisting of instructions to move.
>
> Output the coordinates of a robot after executing the instructions. Initial position of robot is at origin(0, 0).

```
Example:
Input : move = “UDDLRL” 
Output : (-1, -1)
Explanation:
Move U : (0, 0)–(0, 1)
Move D : (0, 1)–(0, 0)
Move D : (0, 0)–(0, -1)
Move L : (0, -1)–(-1, -1)
Move R : (-1, -1)–(0, -1)
Move L : (0, -1)–(-1, -1)
Therefore final position after the complete
movement is: (-1, -1)
```

I got the code working without using the 10x10 grid information. How could I incorporate the 10x10 grid information into my solution in an OOP fashion? My solution doesn't follow the OOP principles.

```
# function to find final position of
# robot after the complete movement

def finalPosition(move): 
    l = len(move)
    countUp, countDown = 0, 0
    countLeft, countRight = 0, 0
 
    # traverse the instruction string 'move'
    for i in range(l): 
        # for each movement increment its respective counter
        if (move[i] == 'U'):
            countUp += 1
        elif(move[i] == 'D'):
            countDown += 1
        elif(move[i] == 'L'):
            countLeft += 1
        elif(move[i] == 'R'):
            countRight += 1
 
    # required final position of robot
    print("Final Position: (", (countRight - countLeft),
          ", ", (countUp - countDown), ")")
 
 
# Driver code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    move = "UDDLLRUUUDUURUDDUULLDRRRR"
    finalPosition(move)
```

Comment: What should the code do differently with vs. without a 10x10 grid?

Comment: I am wondering if I should create a 10X10 grid first. The question just states a 10 X 10 grid. I am guessing that the robot can't go beyond the 10 X 10 area.

Comment: So then you should check that your count cannot become negative and cannot exceed 9, right? Did you try?

Comment: I see. Will give that a shot. @trincot

Comment: @trincot makes a lot more sense now with your solution. +1

Comment: @trincot It might be a bit late but I just realized, with `UDDLLRUUUDUURUDDUULLDRRRR `, I was expecting a final position of (2, 3). But your solution outputs (4, 1). Something seems to be wrong in the solution.

Comment: There are two reasons why the output is different: you added information to the question where it is defined that UP means the Y coordinate increases. I had assumed back then that the Y coordinate moved *down*, like in arrays -- and had I explained this assumption at the top of my answer, but have now edited it. More importantly, your solution allows the robot to temporarily move outside of the 10x10 grid with negative X and Y values, which was something you said should not happen. So I have kept that grid check as it was. The output then is 4, 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixes it:

```
class Robot:

    class Mover:
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x, self.y = x, y

        def new_pos(self, x, y):
            new_x = x + self.x
            new_y = y + self.y
            if (new_x > 9 or new_y > 9):
                raise ValueError("Box dimensions are greater than 10 X 10")
            return new_x, new_y

    WALKS = dict(U=Mover(0, 1), D=Mover(0, -1),
                 L=Mover(-1, 0), R=Mover(1, 0))

    def move(self, moves):
        x = y = 0
        for id in moves:
            x, y = self.WALKS[id].new_pos(x, y)
        return (x,y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    moves2 = "UDDLLRUUUDUURUDDUULLDRRRR"
    robot = Robot()
    print(robot.move(moves2))
```

Output :

```
(2,3)
```

Comment: This allows the robot to move with negative X and Y values outside of the 10x10 grid, and it produces an error when the robot tries to move outside on the two other sides. That an error should be triggered is not specified in the question. It just says that the robot cannot move outside of the area, so I would assume the robot ignores such moves (as if hitting a fence). Moreover, if you call `move` multiple times, the robot doesn't continue from its last position. The Robot does not really remember its position, which is not really OOP style.

Comment: Can you explain why you consider this the correct answer, when you allow the robot to move to negative offsets and not to offsets greater than 9? I don't see the consistency in that...

Answer (score 0):

The way you use your counters makes it less trivial to detect that you would hit the border of the 10x10 grid. Without changing too much, you could replace the `countUp` and `countDown` variables by one `countVertical` variable, and add -1 to it when going up and 1 when going down. Then ignore a move if it would make that counter negative or greater than 9. And obviously you would do the same for horizontal movements.

[**Edit:** After the edit to your question, it turns out that you want the Y-coordinate to be opposite to what I assumed above. So I have changed the sign of the Y-coordinate updates (+1, -1).]

That's really it.

Now to make this more OOP, you could define a `Robot` class, which would maintain its `x` and `y` coordinate. Anyhow it would be good to remove the `print` call out of your function, so the function only deals with the movements, not with the reporting (separation of concern).

Here is how it could work:

```
class Robot:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.position(x, y)
 
    def position(self, x, y):
        self.x = min(9, max(0, x))
        self.y = min(9, max(0, y))

    def move(self, moves):
        for move in moves:
            if move == 'U': 
                self.position(self.x, self.y + 1)
            elif move == 'D':
                self.position(self.x, self.y - 1)
            elif move == 'L':
                self.position(self.x - 1, self.y)
            elif move == 'R':
                self.position(self.x + 1, self.y)
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Invalid direction '{move}'")
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    moves = "UDDLLRUUUDUURUDDUULLDRRRR"
    robot = Robot(0, 0)
    robot.move(moves)
    print(f"Final position: {robot.x}, {robot.y}")
```

Comment: Its not 1 month later. Its just 5 days later. I didn't change the question, just added a sample input/ output.

Comment: Sorry about that month. The sample output showed that the up direction was different from what I had assumed.